# Does vertical pod autoscaler only works with resource requests or it also changes the limits too?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

In the [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/verticalpodautoscaler), it says that:

> Vertical Pod autoscaling frees you from having to think about what
> values to specify for a container’s CPU **requests and limits** and
> memory **requests and limits**. The autoscaler can recommend values
> for CPU and memory requests and limits, or it can automatically update
> the values

However in the [open source vertical pod autoscaler documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/autoscaling/vertical-pod-autoscaler.md#recommendation-model) there are two seemingly contradictory statements:

> VPA is capable of setting container resources (CPU & memory
> request/limit) at Pod submission time.
>
> VPA only controls the resource request of containers. It sets the
> limit to infinity. The request is calculated based on analysis of the
> current and previous runs

I’m confused which one is finally correct, and if there is a capability to get limits recommendations how can I add that to my VPA? so far I have only managed to only get requests recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VPA is capable of setting the limit when you set the `controlledValues` to `RequestAndLimits` option. However, it does not recommend what the limit should be. With this requests are being calculated  based on actual values where limits are calculated based on the current pod's requests and limit relation. This means that if you start the Pod that has 2CPU requests and limit set to 10CPU then VPA will always set te limit to be 1:5. Meaning second quantity (limits) will be always 5 times as large as the first.

You have understand also that `limits` are not used by scheduler, those are just for Kubelet to kill the pods if he ever exceeds those

As for your not correctly working VPA we would need to see some config example to provide any more advice over the internet.

Comment: thanks! where can I found the full list of the VPA available options. I can see them here https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler/pkg/apis/autoscaling.k8s.io/v1/types.go but I couldn't find some documentation on them.

Comment: It seems to be added in the VPA FAQ: https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler/FAQ.md, see https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-are-the-parameters-to-vpa-recommender (there's one for updater as well).